# No aparecen los archivos anteriores a la instalación de la aplicación en Android

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, listview, programación-móvil

En mi código tengo un ListView que lista los archivos pdf en la carpeta "Documentos" del teléfono que se actualiza cuando creas uno, pero los que se han creado anteriormente no aparecen, siguen en la carpeta de documentos y puedes verlos ingresando los archivos en el teléfono, pero no aparecen desde la aplicación.

Este es mi código:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private var pdfFileNames = arrayOf<String>() // Lista de nombres de archivos PDF
    private lateinit var pdfAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> // Adaptador para el ListView

    private lateinit var listView: ListView

    private val documentsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Iniciando la cámara")

        // CONFIGURAMOS VIEWBINDING
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Inicializa los elementos de la interfaz
        listView = binding.listaPdf


        // Inicializa el adaptador para el ListView
        pdfAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdfFileNames)
        listView.adapter = pdfAdapter


        listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selectedFileName = pdfFileNames[position] // Obtiene el nombre del archivo PDF seleccionado
            val selectedFile = File(documentsDirectory, selectedFileName) // Obtiene el archivo PDF correspondiente
            openPdf(selectedFile) // Abre el archivo PDF seleccionado
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        loadPDFs()
    }

    
    //LISTA PDF   
    // Función para cargar los nombres de archivos PDF
    private fun loadPDFs() {
        if (documentsDirectory.exists() && documentsDirectory.isDirectory) {
            pdfFileNames = documentsDirectory
                .listFiles { file -> file.isFile && file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf") }
                .map { it.name }
                .toTypedArray()

            Log.d("PDF Lista","Ruta $documentsDirectory")
            Log.d("PDF Lista","Nº archivos ${pdfFileNames.size}")

            if(pdfFileNames.isNotEmpty()){
                // Actualiza el adaptador del ListView
                pdfAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdfFileNames)
                listView.adapter = pdfAdapter
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se encontraron archivos pdf en la carpeta Documentos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

        
    //PDF
    private fun openPdf(pdfFile: File) {
        val intent = Intent(this, VisorPDF::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("pdf_path", pdfFile.absolutePath)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Intenté llamar a la función loadPDFs en las función `onResume` para que al volver a la pantalla principal se actualizara pero solo carga los que se crean a partir de la nueva instalación.

He intentado agregar un registro para ver cuántos archivos detecta dentro de la carpeta `"/Documentos"` y solo cuenta los archivos nuevos, con un total de 11 (8 de la instalación anterior y 3 pdf creados a partir de la nueva instalación).

He comprobado si los archivos nuevos como los antiguos tienen la misma ruta y la tienen exactamente igual.

> /storage/emulated/0/Documents

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas haciendo uso del método [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

```
private val documentsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

y este método es obsoleto desde Android 10 (API level 29), y el cambio principal es que ahora por cuestiones de seguridad, los archivos unicamente pueden ser guardados y leidos dentro de la estructura de archivos que genera tu aplicación, que es:

```
/data/"package name"/files/
```

Ahora en lugar de usar [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)), debes usar
[getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) :

```
private val documentsDirectory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

---

Si tenías archivos guardados fuera de la estructura

```
/data/"package name"/files/
```

y tu aplicación se compila orientada a Android 10 o posterior, ya no podrás visualizar estos archivos.

Comment: Si ya probé eso y no pude probar si los archivos viejos los leeria porque ni desde el móvil o desde el PC me dejo meter archivos a la carpeta `files`, pero la app también permite elegir un archivo para enviarlo por correo abriendo el explorador de archivos del móvil, y si guardo los archivos dentro de la estructura de la app no me dejara entrar para elegir el archivo, no?